# Sorting JSON File by specific value in PHP and then saving the sorted JSON file

Tags: php, json

I am pretty new to PHP and JSON. I am currently creating a website which has a ranking table for video games. I have created a JSON file with all the information in it:

```
{"id":1,"name":"The Crew","rating":"10","genre":"Racing","release_date":"02.12.2014","developer":"Ivory Tower","publisher":"Ubisoft","platforms":"PS4, Xbox One, PC", "age_restriction":"12"}
{"id":2,"name":"DriveClub","rating":"8","genre":"Racing","release_date":"07.10.2014","developer":"Evolution Studios","publisher":"Sony Interactive Entertainment","platforms":"PS4", "age_restriction":"3"}
{"id":3,"name":"Project CARS","rating":"8","genre":"Racing","release_date":"06.05.2015","developer":"Slightly Mad Studios","publisher":"Slightly Mad Studios","platforms":"PS4, Xbox One, PC", "age_restriction":"3"}
{"id":4,"name":"Project CARS 2","rating":"8","genre":"Racing","release_date":"21.09.2017","developer":"Slightly Mad Studios","publisher":"Slightly Mad Studios","platforms":"PS4, Xbox One, PC", "age_restriction":"3"}
{"id":5,"name":"Dirt Rally","rating":"10","genre":"Racing","release_date":"07.12.2015","developer":"Codemaster","publisher":"Codemaster","platforms":"PS4, Xbox One, PC, MacOs, Linux", "age_restriction":"6"}
{"id":6,"name":"Wreckfest","rating":"8","genre":"Racing","release_date":"15.01.2014","developer":"Bugbear Entertainment","publisher":"THQ Nordic","platforms":"PS4, Xbox One, PC", "age_restriction":"12"}
{"id":7,"name":"Gran Turismo Sport","rating":"8","genre":"Racing","release_date":"17.10.2017","developer":"Polyphony Digitial","publisher":"Polyphony Digital","platforms":"PS4", "age_restriction":"3"}
{"id":8,"name":"F1 2019","rating":"8","genre":"Racing","release_date":"25.06.2019","developer":"Codemaster","publisher":"Codemaster","platforms":"PS4, Xbox One, PC", "age_restriction":"3"}
{"id":9,"name":"Need For Speed Pay Back","rating":"6","genre":"Racing","release_date":"10.11.2017","developer":"Ghost Games","publisher":"EA","platforms":"PS4, Xbox One, PC", "age_restriction":"12"}
{"id":10,"name":"The Crew 2","rating":"7","genre":"Racing","release_date":"31.05.2018","developer":"Ivory Tower","publisher":"Ubisoft","platforms":"PS4, Xbox One, PC", "age_restriction":"12"}
```

I have managed to sort the games by rating, by using this code

```
$data = jsonLoadAllGames("data/json/games.json");
usort($data, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
    return $a->rating > $b->rating ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
});
```

However, I can't figure out how to save the sorted list to that JSON file which is linked to my ranking table. At the moment it is displaying them in the order that they are listed in. The id is needed for displaying the game on another page. (I am not allowed to SQL btw)

I hope this makes sense, if there are any questions feel free to ask. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: try json_encode $data array and give the output to file_put_contents to create a file

Comment: Find where `jsonLoadAllGames()` is defined and then do what it does, but in reverse. Alternatively, find the function that wrote the file in the first place and use that. We can only guess what that any of the might do other than "output something that looks like JSON, but isn't really".

Comment: @sammitch hey sorry for the confusion! The 'jsonLoadAllGames()' hasn't created the data in the file. I have written down the data into the JSON myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = jsonLoadAllGames("data/json/games.json");
usort($data, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
    return $a->rating > $b->rating ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
});

file_put_contents("data/json/mynewfile.json", json_encode($data));
```

Additionnaly, you should check the return value of file_put_contents to check for errors.

If you need the output file with a nice indentation, give JSON_PRETTY_PRINT as second parameter to json_encode.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! I really appreciate the help! Have a good one and stay safe :)

Comment: Thanks, you too. Can you valid the answer :) ?